# Bash script not sourcing

Tags: bash, python-poetry

In my folder where I keep my other bash scripts, I have created this one:

```
#! /bin/bash

source $(poetry env info --path)/bin/activate
```

In a file named `poetry_activate`. In a bash terminal, the autocomplete works, and when I enter `poetry_activate`, the virtual environment is not loaded...

However, if I do `source $(poetry env info --path)/bin/activate`  in the terminal, it works. It also works if I do `. poetry_activate`...

Is there a way to just make the script `poetry_activate` work?

Comment: Subshells can't affect their parent environments. You have to stick the command into a function and source that function on, e.g., shell startup.

Comment: "source that function" ... in a `.bash_rc` or other similar `.` file so it is automatic. You'll have to figure out which one works best in your use-case. See `man bash` and search for INVOCATION. Good luck.

Comment: Here's the thing -- successfully sourcing configuration into the shell that's running your script only has any effect _for the duration of that script_. So your script is sourcing variables in just fine -- they just disappear when the interpreter they were sourced into exits a moment later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you *execute* the script you initiate a subshell; variable assignments made in the subshell are 'lost' when the subshell exits (in this case the `poetry_activate` script exits).

As you've found, when you *source* the script (`. poetry_activate` or `source poetry_activate`) then no subshell is initiated and instead the commands (within the script) are executed within the current shell.

To eliminate the subshell, while also removing the need to `source` the script, you could replace the shell script with a function, eg:

```
poetry_activate() { source $(poetry env info --path)/bin/activate; }

# or

poetry_activate() {
    source $(poetry env info --path)/bin/activate
}
```

**NOTES:**

- in the first example the trailing `;` is required to separate the code from the closing `}`
- add this to your `.profile` or `.bashrc`
- assumes your `PATH` has been configured so the OS can find `poetry`

Now instead of referencing the script you reference the function; an example of referencing the function from the command line:

```
$ poetry_activate
```

Comment: by the way, I prefer to `.` a file with that function into my `.bashrc` file. It makes things cleaner, I think ;)

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. that works, too; I actually have a separate directory with all of my custom functions residing in individual files; my `.profile` then has a loop that sources the individual function definition files; for this answer I didn't want to wander too far off topic hence the direct entry in the `.profile` / `.bashrc`

Comment: ohhhhh that's even better!!!